# Is CHECK better then invalid data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm writing a code for a database. I have a table with log of machines activity, looking like:

```
CREATE TABLE Work(  
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,   
   machine_ID integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,   
   start_work timestamp,
   etc...
);
```

I know machine_ID can be in 1 to 5.

Here my question comes: 
Are there any benefits of using `CHECK(machine_ID >= 1 AND machine_ID <=5)`?
Wouldn't it be better to accept polluted data in order to repair possible bugs later, or even to use the possibility to clean up the data?

Comment: I would always use the check constraint. Invalid data should only be allowed in very rare cases

Comment: +1. You really don't want garbage in your database. Once it is in there, it is difficult to get rid of it.

Comment: You're assuming that the "polluted" data will a) be easily identifiable and b) repairable. Whether or not these things are true will depend a lot on your specific circumstances. I.e. even the check constraint won't help you if machine 3 starts reporting itself as machine 4.

Comment: Check constraint will possibly make it faster for you to detect problems as it will throw error, while storing polluted data would require you to do periodic checks on it. It will however cost some processing power and will prevent any part of the row from being stored (polluted or not), so you might need to program around it on whatever is inserting that data (like retry on error after XX minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is more appropriate as a comment.

But a column called `machine_id` should not be validated using a `check` constraint.  Instead, you should have a table -- say `machines` -- that is a reference table for machines.

Your code should use a `foreign key` constraint.  This is a special type of data validation called *relational integrity*.

As for your question.  In my experience, it is usually better to capture errors when they go into the database.  Bad data in the database usually leads to problems further down the road -- problems that could have been avoided.

Answer (score 0):

That will be okey if you want to limit how may id can be in your database, but nothing else.

Comment: You mean, check will be okay only for that purpose?

Comment: Yeah, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is massively subjective, with different approaches and opinions, and is highly dependent on your business case.

One principle is to keep things simple, but even what *that* means is subjective.

- Reject Early

  In a pre-processing layer, apply rules to the data being received.  As soon as possible reject any row/file/source and request re-submission.

  This makes it clear what has been accepted, what hasn't been accepted, how to deal with such scenarios, etc.

- Consume Everything

  Where failures can be complicated and varied, a database can often be the best place to do analysis to understand the source, cause, magnitude and/or impact of failures.  In which case ingesting everything can be beneficial.

  But that can have a potentially uncontrolled impact.  As such, my general experience of this is to have a separate staging area in the database.  Essentially as unstructured as possible, to allow as much data in as possible.  But even that's not always helpful.  If you use strings for all fields, you can accept data that would normally have to be accepted.  But even then, what if you have a file with 9 columns being supplied for a table of 8 columns?  You could accept the whole row as a single string, but analyzing that for meaningful results will be close to impossible.

What this means in your case depends on the project you are working on, and that's what you haven't described.

My personal default position is to re-categorise certain source data failures as predicted/business-as-usual inconsistencies.  You can then structure your staging area to handle these, for reporting, reconciliation, remedial action, etc.  And, more importantly, explicitly build them in to all related business processes.  Doing so will introduce a cost, which can be estimated against the benefit of accommodating them, with the intention of only accommodating inconsistencies where it's actually a material benefit.  *(Rather than just being a hoarder that keeps everything just in case it might help someone someday, maybe.)*

Whatever direction that goes, however, the operational database itself (not the staging area) is heavily structured, with integrity constraints in place to prevent bugs, unexpected inputs, etc, from corrupting existing data or causing unexpected, unmonitored consequences.

If you truly believe that your operational database *(be that transactional, analytical, or anything else)* would benefit from being absent some/many/all of these data integrity tools, then a SQL Relational Database is probably the wrong tool for you.  Instead consider the enormous number of unstructured data storage and processing platforms.

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of different considerations.

Firstly, I prefer not to use check constraints for business rules that are likely to change - I don't want to roll out a database schema change (and a check constraint is a schema change) in response to a predictable business event. Adding or removing machines feels like a predictable business event; so as @gordonLinoff suggests, I'd recommend using a foreign key to the "machines" table.

Secondly, I don't like "hidden code" - from a development and maintenance point of view, I like to keep all the validation as intelligible as possible. Check constraints and triggers are relatively "hidden", hard to document, hard to debug, hard to test for non-trivial use cases; foreign keys, on the other hand, are explicit and developers expect them.